# How to set parent variable within a loop in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, global-variables, until-loop

I have been trying to learn loops, and I have the following:

```
Guessing_Game() {
echo "Guessing Game!"
set loopSwitch = 0
until [[ $loopSwitch == 1 ]];
    echo $loopSwitch
    do
        read -p "Guess a number between 1 and 10: " userGuess
        if [[ $userGuess == 6 ]];
        then
            echo "Well done! You win."
        else
            echo "Incorrect guess."
        fi

    read -p "Would you like to play again? (y/n)" playAgain
    if [[ $playAgain == "n" ]];
        then
            set loopSwitch = 1
    fi

done
}
```

From what I have read, as the loopSwitch variable was set outside of the subshell, it can only change the value within that subshell?

How can I go about setting the loopSwitch variable so that I can exit the loop?

I have tried echoing out the variable $loopSwitch through several portions of the code - just after the entry into the until loop, inside the last if statement - and nothing is output, so I'm thinking it just doesn't exist within the until loop?

For the

```
set loopSwitch = 1
```

portion, I've tried:

```
set loopSwitch = 1
set $loopSwitch = 1
loopSwitch = 1
$loopSwitch = 1
```

Any help would be appreciated, whether that be with the code or constructs as a whole.

Comment: Use `local loopSwitch` at begin of your function

Comment: if you really put the `echo` before the `do`, the loop exited immediately. note there are no subshell environments in the code shown

Comment: cf [Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) - note that `test-commands` is plural, only the exit status of the final one matters

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. Do you mean to set local just after Guessing_Game() or within the until loop?  I am trying to echo my variable also, and it keeps printing a blank line

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code (e.g. mistaken use of `set`).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: @pjh thank you ever so much.  This has been invaluable. Looks like I was doing several things wrong, mainly incorrect assignment of the variable.  Thank you!

Comment: Your `set` command does not set any variable at all. For the use of the `set` command, see the bash man page, section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_, so your question does not really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there is no subshell in your code. I think you probably saw code like

```
num=27; seq 3 | while IFS= read -r line; do num="$line"; echo "inside: $num"; done; echo "outside: $num"
```

which would output 1, 2, 3, 27 and misunderstood why that outputs 27 instead of 3 at the end. It's not because loops run in a subshell, but because the commands on both sides of a pipe (|) run in a subshell. That's why you'd use command substitution (`<(command)`) to write

```
num=27; while IFS= read -r line; do num="$line"; echo "inside: $num"; done < <(seq 3); echo "outside: $num"
```

which would output 1, 2, 3, 3 instead. See mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024.

Regarding the code in your question, FWIW I'd write it as:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Guessing_Game() {
    local keepPlaying theNumber userGuess
    echo 'Guessing Game!'

    theNumber=$(shuf -n 1 -i 1-10)

    until [[ "$keepPlaying" =~ [nN] ]]; do
        echo "$keepPlaying"
        IFS= read -r -p 'Guess a number between 1 and 10: ' userGuess
        if (( userGuess == theNumber )); then
            echo "Well done! You win."
        else
            echo "Incorrect guess."
        fi

        IFS= read -r -p 'Would you like to play again? ([y]/n)' keepPlaying
    done
}

Guessing_Game
```

The changes I made were:

1. Added a shebang to find the first `bash` in the callers `PATH`.
2. Added the call to the function.
3. Used local variables.
4. Used arithmetic operators `((...))` for numeric comparisons.
5. Used `IFS=` and `-r` on the `read`s as you always should unless you have a specific need to remove either of them, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).
6. Quoted the variables as you always should unless you have a specific **need** to remove them, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.
7. Got rid of `loopSwitch` as it meant almost exactly the same thing as `playAgain` and then renamed `playAgain` to `keepPlaying` so it made slightly more sense for the first loop iteration too.
8. Defined a variable to hold the target number instead of hard-coding it in the comparison for ease of future maintenance/enhancements (e.g. if you wanted to add a print statement to dump it).
9. Make the target number a random value between 1 and 10 instead of a hard-coded `6`. If you don't have `shuf` that can do this job just google "shell random number between 1 and 10" or similar.
10. Made the test for `keepPlaying` case-independent.
11. Removed the `set`s as they're unnecessary and I don't know why anyone would use that.
12. Used a more common style of indenting.

Comment: This is great information. Appreciate you taking the time. I managed to get my code working from the comments above but this improves greatly on my code, so shall incorporate these going forward. Thanks ever so much!